# Is it possible to do SQL injection (HIGH Level) on Damn Vulnerable Web App?

Tags: php, mysql

I searched all over google to see how it would be possible to bypass the following (it's from the high level of security from DVWA):

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 
    $id = stripslashes($id); 
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id); 

    if (is_numeric($id)){ 

    $getid = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($getid) or die('<pre>' . mysql_error() . '</pre>' ); 

    $num = mysql_numrows($result); 

    $i=0; 

    while ($i < $num) { 

        $first = mysql_result($result,$i,"first_name"); 
        $last = mysql_result($result,$i,"last_name"); 

        echo '<pre>'; 
        echo 'ID: ' . $id . '<br>First name: ' . $first . '<br>Surname: ' . $last; 
        echo '</pre>'; 

        $i++; 
    } 
}
```

Is it possible to crack that?

For those who aren't familiar with DVWA, here is a youtube video about it:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMV0JZVxvdQ

Also, my other concern is on Medium level. It does have the `mysql_real_escape_string()` working, but when you use the same SQL injection from Low level AND you remove the quotes, it bypasses the protection. Why is that? How come it was so easy to bypass `mysql_real_escape string`?

The code (concise version) of the Medium level is this:

```
   $id = $_GET['id']; 
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id); 
    $getid = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = $id";
```

I want to use PDO's as it's probably much safer. Please let me know your thoughts on that.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi, my question is about Damn Vulnerable Web App but I just added the whole code if needed. Thanks

Comment: What levels are you talking about? Is it something specific to DVWA?

Comment: Yes it's specific of DVWA. There are levels of security (low, medium, high) to practice on SQL injection. Low level doesn't have any protection against SQL injections. Medium level just has `mysql_real_escape_string` and High is in my post. I'll put the code of the medium as well.

Answer (score 2):

The addition of `is_numeric` would not make this a very likely full-blown sql attack, but `is_numeric` is just not very exact:

```
is_numeric('0xdeadbeef') // true
is_numeric('10e3') // true
```

It's probably better to use filters:

```
if (false !== ($id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
}
```

Comment: I prefer just cast it like `$id = (int) $_GET['id'];`

Comment: @RomanNewaza imo it's better to avoid making a query that will most likely not yield anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem you have. I don't know how to crack it neither.

But I think I have an answer for the problem in Medium level, I think it's a programmer's error.

```
$getid = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = $id"
```

Notice that in low and high level you have quotes in $id, not in Medium...I think that's the point. 
If you'd have this:

```
$getid = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id'"
```

I'm pretty sure that it wouldn't be so easy to bypass mysql_real_escape string in Medium level.

In other words, I'm pretty sure that if you didn't have the quotes in High Level, you could do the injection as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the medium level just use: `1 and 1=1 order by X`.

All of the author's queries are low level, but you can replace the name of a table with hex code `0x...`, for example `where table_name=0x12345`. If we use a string char we will have an error because the `'` is not allowed.