# security filter in php for rfi

Tags: php, security, include

Well I look a little about rfi and php security and found this include code in dvwa:

```
<?php
    $file = $_GET['page']; //The page we wish to display 
    // Only allow include.php
    if ( $file != "include.php" ) {
        echo "ERROR: File not found!";
                echo "$file";
        exit;
    }
    include($file);

?>
```

Well i dont understand why this code its not secure.
I talked with some security peoples and they say this code its not secure and I shouldn't use it. I know that its beter to turn of the include option, **but i think this fiter can't be passed**.

I try a lot of comman attacks, and non of them pass it.
I will be glad to hear your opinions

Comment: Just for completeness: [*Help with PHP Remote File Inclusion in Damn Vulnerable Web Application* on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/52794/539).

Comment: Well, some poeples need to read specific things to not ignore you.
I have a lot to say about this "security forum" that i will not open here.
I start to think that what i am looking for is way beind the common knowledge..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already said in a [comment to your question on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52794/help-with-php-remote-file-inclusion-in-damn-vulnerable-web-application#comment83364_52794), my impression of the high level challenges of DWVA that I have seen so far is that they are supposed to be safe. There have been other questions about the exploitability of high level challenges (especially the SQL injection: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10809665/53114), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17381302/53114), [#3](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/43294/539)) and the unified opinion tends to non-exploitable.

The [high level file inclusion challenge](https://github.com/RandomStorm/DVWA/blob/master/vulnerabilities/fi/source/high.php), where your code is taken from, is likewise:

`include` only gets reached if the condition `$file != "include.php"` is not fulfilled as otherwise `exit` will terminate the runtime. Since `$file`’s value is taken from `$_GET['page']`, it is a string (e. g., `?page=foo`), an array (e. g., `?page[foo]=bar`), or `null` (e. g., only `?page` or missing entirely).

Now let’s see [what happens when comparing these types](http://php.net/types.comparisons) with a string:

- an array is never equivalent to a string
- `null` is only equivalent an empty string
- a string is only equivalent to another string if it is composed of the same sequence of bytes, i. e., the string values are identical

So the only way to get past this `if` is `?page=include.php` as otherwise the `include` would not be reached due to the positive `if` condition.

Comment: well, what will happen if we will add php code to the file name? it will get executed?

Comment: @OrHalimi The PHP code would still be interpreted as file name.

Answer (score 2):

This is very safe except you are echoing the file without `htmlentities()` thus there is an XSS flaw.

POC : `mywebsite.com/script_name.php?page=<script>alert('XSS')</script>`

Another way to do it is :

```
<?php
    $whitelist = array('include.php','some_other_file.php','another.php');
    $file = $_GET['page']; //The page we wish to display 

    if (!in_array($file, $whitelist)){
        header("Location: /");
    }
    include($file);

?>
```

Even the "file not found" thing is too much, if someone tries to mess up with your application you must tell him as less as possible.

Personally I would simply redirect to your homepage using php `header()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the replie, you are right it doesn't solve xss but the xss wont get store anyway :-)

Comment: Even not stored XSS are a real threat. One could share a specially crafted link from your server to mass users.